# MENU item selected

Tags: menuitem

I have a menu created in ASP.NET master page. I have implemented CSS properties to menu items like hover and link, but I am not able to implement the properties for changing the color of the selected item in the menu.

Do I need to write any JavaScript or jQuery code for identifying the selected item in the menu? Please help me, as I am new to this type of menu items.

Answer (score 0):

if you mean that you want to change the color of a menu item persistently (like, say, the current page tab of a navigation menu is always some particular color), you can do this in ASP by adding a class or id attribute to the menu item when it is clicked. I'm not an ASP kind of guy, but in PHP, you can do it by doing something like:

```
<li><a href="/?page=n">page #n</a></li>
```

and then when the page in question is loaded, the navigation code should say something like:

if $_GET[page]=n then echo " class=\"selected\"" into the anchor tag.

know what i mean? I didn't type out the code for the above if statement because I'm pretty sure ASP is a little different from PHP, and you would have to translate anyway, but I hope this is helpful.

Andy

Edit:    ## Here's my ASP guesswork after a brief encounter with google: ##

```
<li 
<%

if Request.QueryString("page")==n Then
    Response.Write(" class=\"selected\"")
%>
><a href="/?page=n">Page #n</a></li>
```

Comment: Hi i have done like this  <li><a href="/?page=n">page #n</a></li>
already , My question is i am not able to get the current selected item in the menu with different colour ,

Comment: edited my solution with some ASP guesswork... It should get you going in the right direction if it's not already functional. Notice the ASP goes inside the opening li tag. It tests to see if the item in question is the current page, and if it is, it adds the "selected" class to the li. in your css, you should define a .selected class to have the color properties you desire. Hope this helps!